# Problem with box when I refresh my page in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my program because I have buttons which work with a prompt() but when I refresh my page, it's like the prompt work also because the box appears before I can access my page.(it's a french program)

[image: Here the HTML program]

Here the JS field:

```
// Tableau pour stocker les éléments
    var elements = [];

// Fonction pour afficher la liste d'éléments
function afficherListe() {
    var listeDiv = document.getElementById("liste");
    listeDiv.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var elementDiv = document.createElement("div");
      elementDiv.textContent = elements[i];
      listeDiv.appendChild(elementDiv);
    }
  }

// Fonction pour ajouter un élément à la liste
  function ajouterElement() {
    var nouvelElement = prompt("Entrez un nouvel élément :");
    if (nouvelElement) {
      elements.push(nouvelElement);
      afficherListe();
    }
  }

// Fonction pour modifier un élément existant dans la liste
  function modifierElement() {
    var ancienneValeur = prompt("Entrez la valeur à modifier :");
    var index = elements.indexOf(ancienneValeur);
    
    if (index !== -1) {
      var nouvelElement = prompt("Entrez la nouvelle valeur de l'élément :");
      if (nouvelElement !== null) {
        elements[index] = nouvelElement;
        afficherListe();
      }
    } else {
      alert("L'élément avec la valeur spécifiée n'a pas été trouvé dans la liste.");
    }
  }

// Fonction pour supprimer un élément de la liste
  function supprimerElement() {
    var supValeur = prompt("Entrez la valeur de l'élément à supprimer :");
    var index = elements.indexOf(supValeur);
    if (index !== -1) {
      elements.splice(index, 1);
      afficherListe();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to be more clear about what the problem is. Right now I cannot understand. I would also suggest translating the code into english, because it is really hard to understand the context from the code either and if someone else in the future lands on this question, they wouldn't understand either.

Comment: I think nobody understand this problem. And like @Swiffy mentions, don't write your code in french. It's not only hard for others on this site. It is considered good practice because for now, future developers have to be french on this project :)

Comment: I'd closed the question as a duplicate, but now I'm not entirely sure that was correct.  The question is indeed very unclear.  But if the problem is that you're calling `prompt()` when the page first loads and you don't see the UI yet then that's because you're calling `prompt()` when the page first loads.  `prompt()` is a blocking operation.  If you're looking to build a better user experience then I'd recommend avoiding `prompt()` in general, perhaps instead creating an in-page interface with a "modal dialog".

Comment: The page works as expected. Remove the inline execution of the functions that shows a prompt and just have the onClick.

Comment: Posting images of code is really not a thought-out move. You just wasted world-wide silica and made the job of someone who wants to help you much harder.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<script>` tags are executing your functions `ajouterElement, modifierElement,` and `supprimerElement` when your page is loaded. If you remove these from the `script` tags, then they will only be invoked when your `onclick` events fire.

Comment: Why the downvotes. This is the actual answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You only want the prompts when the buttons are clicked

Here is a version using delegation instead of inline event handling.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // Tableau pour stocker les éléments
  const elements = [];
  const listeDiv = document.getElementById("liste");

  // Fonction pour afficher la liste d'éléments
  const afficherListe = () => {
    listeDiv.innerHTML = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      let elementDiv = document.createElement("div");
      elementDiv.textContent = elements[i];
      listeDiv.appendChild(elementDiv);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("buttons").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest("button");
    if (!tgt) return; // not a button

    // Fonction pour ajouter un élément à la liste
    if (tgt.matches("#btn-ajouter")) {
      let nouvelElement = prompt("Entrez un nouvel élément :");
      if (nouvelElement) {
        if (elements.indexOf(nouvelElement) === -1) {
          elements.push(nouvelElement);
        } else {
          alert("L'élément avec la valeur spécifiée est deja trouvé dans la liste.");
        }
      }
    } else if (tgt.matches("#btn-modifier")) {
      // Fonction pour modifier un élément existant dans la liste
      let ancienneValeur = prompt("Entrez la valeur à modifier :");
      if (!ancienneValeur) return;
      let index = elements.indexOf(ancienneValeur);

      if (index !== -1) {
        let nouvelElement = prompt("Entrez la nouvelle valeur de l'élément :");
        if (nouvelElement !== null) {
          elements[index] = nouvelElement;
          afficherListe();
        }
      } else {
        alert("L'élément avec la valeur spécifiée n'a pas été trouvé dans la liste.");
      }
    } else if (tgt.matches("#btn-supprimer")) {
      // Fonction pour supprimer un élément de la liste
      let supValeur = prompt("Entrez la valeur de l'élément à supprimer :");
      if (supValeur) {
        let index = elements.indexOf(supValeur);
        if (index !== -1) {
          elements.splice(index, 1);
        }
      } else {
        alert("L'élément avec la valeur spécifiée n'a pas été trouvé dans la liste.");
      }
    }
    afficherListe();
  });
});
```

```html
<h1>Liste d'éléments</h1>
<div id="liste"></div>
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="btn-ajouter">Ajouter</button>
  <button id="btn-modifier">Modifier</button>
  <button id="btn-supprimer">Supprimer</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoted because you explained yourself the other answer is the correct one.

Comment: @Wimanicesir That is just silly. Why punish an improvement